# How to know if the variables are statistically significant to the model in an R lme4 model?

Tags: r, p-value, random-effects

I have Y (dependent variable) and I have multiple X (independent variables) in mixed linear random effect model. I want to know which variables are statistically significant in an automated way

I have tried the following code to obtain P-value through ANOVA, but it shows a decreased values of P-value every time I added a new variable. It does not seem too realistic though.

```
library(lme4)
data = read.csv(Path)

#Statistical Difference (First try)
modelnull.model = lmer(Y ~ (1|x1), data=data, REML=FALSE)
model1.model = lmer(Y ~ (1|x1)+ (1|x2), data=data, REML=FALSE)
anova(modelnull.model,model1.model)

#Statistical Difference 2 (Second try)
model1.model = lmer(Y ~ (1|x1)+ (1|x2), data=data, REML=FALSE)
model2.model = lmer(Y ~ x3 + (1|x1)+ (1|x2), data=data, REML=FALSE)
anova(model1.model,model2.model)

#Statistical Difference 3 (third try)
model1.model = lmer(Y ~ x3+ (1|x1)+ (1|x2), data=data, REML=FALSE)
model2.model = lmer(Y ~ x3 + (1|x1)+ (1|x2)+(1|x4), data=data,REML=FALSE)
anova(model1.model,model2.model)
```

I want to know how to automate the whole thing for all available variables, and if what I did is okay in terms of Generalized mixed linear modeling.

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html

Comment: Try to move your question to Cross Validated